# free(): invalid next size (fast) ao tentar liberar memória

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, struct

Tenho essa `struct` em uma estrutura de dados e preciso liberar a memória com ela utilizada:

```
typedef struct
{

  int capacityOfElements; //capacidade do vetor

  int numberOfElements;   //número de elementos presentes no vetor

  int *data;              //elementos do vetor

}tVector;
```

para isso estou utilizando a função `free()` onde teoricamente, liberaria primeiro `V->data` e dps `V` para liberar toda a memória utilizada. Porém a chamada `free(V->data)` dá o seguinte erro:

> Error in `./V': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001d82030
>   Aborted (core dumped)

alguém sabe como corrigir isso?

---

```
tVector* create(int n)
{
  tVector* newVector = malloc(sizeof(tVector));                               

if(!newVector)
  printf("error in the Malloc process for newVector.\n");

  newVector->data = malloc(newVector->capacityOfElements *sizeof(int));       


if(!(newVector->data))
  printf("error in the Malloc process for newVector->data.\n");

  newVector->capacityOfElements=n;                                            
  newVector->numberOfElements=0;                                              

  return newVector;
```

Comment: Você instancia a tVector usando malloc?

Comment: sim, aqui segue a função em que uso malloc

Comment: Já experimentaste liberar a memória de cada um individualmente ?

Comment: `newVector->capacityOfElements` não está atribuido um valor quando fazes o `malloc()`

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta assim

```
tVector *create(int n) {
    tVector *newVector = malloc(sizeof *newVector);
    if (!newVector) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in the Malloc process for newVector.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FILURE);
    }

    // newVector->capacityOfElements nao esta atribuido             <=====
    newVector->data = malloc(n * sizeof *newVector->data);
    //                      ^^^ usa n                               <=====

    if (!newVector->data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in the Malloc process for newVector->data.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newVector->capacityOfElements = n;
    newVector->numberOfElements = 0;
    return newVector;
}
```

Para alocar a memoria faz

```
tVector *ponteiro = create(42); // exits on error
```

e, posteriormente, para libertar a memória

```
free(ponteiro->data);
free(ponteiro);
```

Os erros "invalid next size" normalmente indicam erros na gestão de memória: fazer `free()` a blocos não obtidos por `malloc()`; escrever além do limite de blocos; assumir (erradamente) que ponteiros e `int`s teem o mesmo tamanho; etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int capacityOfElements; //capacidade do vetor
  int numberOfElements;   //número de elementos presentes no vetor
  int *data;              //elementos do vetor
} tVector;

static tVector* create(int n)
{
   tVector* newVector = malloc(sizeof(tVector));                               

   if (!newVector)
   {
      printf("error in the Malloc process for newVector\n");
      return NULL;
   }

   // no original:
   // newVector->data = malloc(newVector->capacityOfElements *sizeof(int));
   // pode nao alocar memoria e retornar NULL, porque capacityOfElements ainda nao foi inicializado

   newVector->data = malloc(n*sizeof(int));       
   if (!newVector->data)
   {
      printf("error in the Malloc process for newVector->data\n");
      free(newVector);
      return NULL;
   }

   newVector->capacityOfElements = n;
   newVector->numberOfElements = 0;    

   return newVector;
}

static void destroy(tVector* v)
{
    if (!v) return;
    free(v->data);
    free(v);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("criando vetor de 10 elementos\n");
    tVector* v = create(10);

    if (!v)
    {
       printf("erro ao tentar criar vetor de 10 elementos\n");
       exit(1);
    }

    printf("destruindo vetor de 10 elementos\n");
    destroy(v);
}
```